# How to monitor heroku worker dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I usually just run "heroku run rake jobs:work" from the command line. The great thing about this apporach is that I get intimidate feedback on whether a job failed or not and what jobs are currently processing.

However, now I need to run "heroku ps:scale worker=1"

Is there a way to see what the worker is processing just like with the rake task via the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the heroku command like to access the log of the worker.

`heroku logs -t --ps worker` will show you what is currently being executed on your worker.

I also recommend to use `gem workless` which scales your worker up only when needed. This can save you a lot of money

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say specifically what queue you are running, but it sounds like delayed_job.  If so, you can install the [delayed_job_web](https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web) gem. Basic setup is as simple as adding it you your `Gemfile` and adding a route for it.  Then you can browser to your site /delayed_job and manage the jobs.